# Trouble trying to find and replace text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an application that replaces the spaces in some data with commas and returns the updated file, however the code i've created so far doesn't seem to be having much effect, could anybody point out where i'm going wrong?

```
  public IActionResult FormatFile()
    {
        var webroot = _env.WebRootPath;
        var filepath = TempData["filepath"].ToString();
        string[] reader = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(webroot, filepath));
        foreach (var line in reader)
        {
            if(line.Contains("  "))
            {
                line.Replace("  ", ",");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, reader);
            }
        }


        return Content(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath));
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `line.Contains("  ")` has two spaces. I guess you need single space. Like `line.Contains(" ")`

Comment: `Replace` does not modify string, it returns a new one

Comment: Ahh I should have mentioned its copied from an excel file so the spaces are bigger, i've tried both with normal sized space and double sized space to no effect

Comment: @Jackington what do you mean "spaces are bigger"? What's the ASCII code of this "bigger spaces"?

Comment: Update this line. `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, line.Replace(" ", ","));`

Comment: All of the above + your filepath does not make sense to me. `Path.Combine`? really? Is `filepath` a path or just a filename? If the former, `Combine` seems wrong, if the latter, `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, reader)` seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes. First `Replace` will not made any change to object it will return updated object. So you need to write `line = line.Replace("  ", ",");`.

Second thing you are writing `reader` object instead of `line`. It should be like `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, line.Replace(" ", ","));`

Complete code will be like below.

```
public IActionResult FormatFile()
{
    var webroot = _env.WebRootPath;
    var filepath = TempData["filepath"].ToString();
    string[] reader = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(webroot, filepath));
    foreach (var line in reader)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, line.Replace(" ", ","));
    }

    return Content(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath));
}
```

Comment: Almost! but the second argument in WriteallLines needs a string array rather than just a string